# What or who is Igidallru?

Tags: sumerian, akkadian

In [Did Greeks and Romans allow for belief in only some of their gods?](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/a/2619/4105), Igidallru is mentioned:

> Here is for example Odysseus killing the Cyclops, I meant Nergal killing Igidallru

As [a comment](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/2618/did-greeks-and-romans-allow-for-belief-in-only-some-of-their-gods#comment7950_2619) points out, this apparently is the only reference to "Igidallru" on the internet:

> As far as I can see, this apparently is the only place on the internet that the word "Igidallru" appears. Perhaps it has another transliteration? – mattdm

Gibet then offers [some alternative transliterations](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/2618/did-greeks-and-romans-allow-for-belief-in-only-some-of-their-gods#comment7951_2619):

> @mattdm The internet is not the de facto source This is just the source of brilliant shortcuts. Igidalru/igedelu/igetela appears, fairly quite rarely in some Akkadian stories It was identified by René Labat, just because in Sumerian (not Akkadian) igi.dili means precisely one eye. - Gibet

Unfortunately, none of the proposed alternatives produced any usable results.

What or who is Igidallru?

Comment: @Gibet I was hoping you would answer this.

Comment: @Gibet Do you mean [this book](https://books.google.de/books?id=orSMAQAACAAJ&source=gbs_ViewAPI&redir_esc=y) ?

Answer (score 1):

### Potentially a One-Eyed Monster

There appears to be a (weakly supported?) theory that a lost Nergal myth depicts him fighting a Cyclops like creature.

Quoting directly from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nergal):

> Andrew R. George proposes that a myth presently unknown from textual records dealt with Nergal's combat with a one-eyed monster, the igitelû. He notes that Akkadian omen texts from Susa and from the Sealand archives appears to indicate that one-eyed creatures were known as igidalu, igidaru or igitelû, possibly a loanword from Sumerian igi.dili ("one eye"), and that the only god associated with them was Nergal, who in one such omen texts is identified as the slayer of an igitelû.

The reference Wikipedia cites is George's [book](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/303824582_Nergal_and_the_Babylonian_cyclops) *Bibliotheca Orientalis* which as a section called *Nergal and the Babylonian Cyclops*.